# Adding JavaScript to my Plotly Dash app (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm building a dashboard using Dash in Python. I have configured all the graphs nicely (it's running on the [server here](https://covid19-visualisation-seb.herokuapp.com/)) and the next step is to create a responsive navbar and a footer. Currently looks like this:

[image]

And when I shrink the width, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to add functionality to this button so it would hide the three links on click. I'm trying to toggle the CSS 'active' attribute using JavaScript with this piece of code:

```
 var toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
 var navBarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

 function toggleFunction() {
     navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
 }

 toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleFunction)
```

Basically, when the `navbar-links` class is active, I want it to be set as `display: flex`, and when it's not active I want it to be `display: none`

The HTML elements defined in Python screen are here:

```
    html.Nav([

    html.Div('Covid-19 global data Dashboard', className='dashboard-title'),

    html.A([html.Span(className='bar'),
            html.Span(className='bar'),
            html.Span(className='bar')],
           href='#', className='toggle-button'),

    html.Div(
        html.Ul([
            html.Li(html.A('Linked-In', href='#')),
            html.Li(html.A('Source Code', href='#')),
            html.Li(html.A('CSV Data', href='#'))
        ]),
        className='navbar-links'),

], className='navbar')
```

I didn't expect that there would be issues with accessing elements through JavaScript. After doing some research I found out that JavaScript when executes `getElementsByClassName` function the returned value is null. That is because the function is run before the page is rendered (as far as I understand). It gives me this error:

[image]

This project is getting quite big, so I don't know which parts should I include in this post, but I will share the [git repository](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/Covid19-visualisation) and the [preview of the page](https://covid19-visualisation-seb.herokuapp.com/). Is there an easy solution to it?

Comment: I think you need to create a function that initializes on document or window load time. The JS has probably already run before element `toggle-button` has been loaded, hence 'undefined error'...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Comment: I think it does, but I don't know how to implement that into my JS script due to my JS knowledge limitations

Comment: You can add an event listener for the `load` event. For an example see the second example of the second answer of the linked post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096571/9098350)). You can put the code in your question inside the handler function for the load event and that will probably work.

Comment: I don't think you need javascript for this btw. You could also probably do it with a callback in Dash.

Comment: Yeah I was researching how to do it with dash, but couldn't find it. Similar event is described [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/append-script-when-dash-components-are-loaded/8023/3)

but dash.dependencies Event module is no longer available on Dash

Comment: I changed my JavaScript to this but it still doesn't work. I'm probably doing something wrong

`var toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
var navBarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

window.onload = function toggleFunction() {
    navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
}

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleFunction)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash callback solution (no Javascript):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

navbar_base_class = "navbar-links"

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Nav(
    [
        html.Div("Covid-19 global data Dashboard", className="dashboard-title"),
        html.A(
            id="toggle-button",
            children=[
                html.Span(className="bar"),
                html.Span(className="bar"),
                html.Span(className="bar"),
            ],
            href="#",
            className="toggle-button",
        ),
        html.Div(
            id="navbar-links",
            children=html.Ul(
                children=[
                    html.Li(html.A("Linked-In", href="#")),
                    html.Li(html.A("Source Code", href="#")),
                    html.Li(html.A("CSV Data", href="#")),
                ],
            ),
            className=navbar_base_class,
        ),
    ],
    className="navbar",
)


@app.callback(
    Output("navbar-links", "className"),
    Input("toggle-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("navbar-links", "className"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def callback(n_clicks, current_classes):
    if "active" in current_classes:
        return navbar_base_class
    return navbar_base_class + " active"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The idea of the code above is to take the `toggle-button` click as `Input` and the current value of `navbar-links` as `State`. We can use this state to determine if we should add the `active` class or remove it. The new `className` value is returned in the callback.

---

Javascript solution:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0];
  var navBarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-links")[0];

  function toggleFunction() {
    navBarLinks.classList.toggle("active");
  }

  toggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleFunction);
});
```

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

`DOMContentLoaded` would be preferable to use, but it only works for me with `load`.

Comment: I just implemented python solution, which is great help, thank you so much! I tried JS solution first, but It didn't work. That still solves my problem so you don't worry about it

Answer (score 3):

You can defer the execution of JavaScript code until after React has loaded via the `DeferScript` component from [dash-extensions](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#deferscript). Here is a small example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from html import unescape
from dash_extensions import DeferScript


mxgraph = r'{&quot;highlight&quot;:&quot;#0000ff&quot;,&quot;nav&quot;:true,&quot;resize&quot;:true,&quot;toolbar&quot;:&quot;zoom layers lightbox&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;:&quot;_blank&quot;,&quot;xml&quot;:&quot;&lt;mxfile host=\&quot;app.diagrams.net\&quot; modified=\&quot;2021-06-07T06:06:13.695Z\&quot; agent=\&quot;5.0 (Windows)\&quot; etag=\&quot;4lPJKNab0_B4ArwMh0-7\&quot; version=\&quot;14.7.6\&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram id=\&quot;YgMnHLNxFGq_Sfquzsd6\&quot; name=\&quot;Page-1\&quot;&gt;jZJNT4QwEIZ/DUcToOriVVw1JruJcjDxYho60iaFIaUs4K+3yJSPbDbZSzN95qPTdyZgadm/GF7LAwrQQRyKPmBPQRzvktidIxgmwB4IFEaJCUULyNQvEAyJtkpAswm0iNqqegtzrCrI7YZxY7Dbhv2g3r5a8wLOQJZzfU4/lbByoslduPBXUIX0L0cheUrugwk0kgvsVojtA5YaRDtZZZ+CHrXzukx5zxe8c2MGKntNgknk8bs8fsj3+KtuDhxP+HZDVU5ct/RhatYOXgGDbSVgLBIG7LGTykJW83z0dm7kjklbaneLnEnlwFjoL/YZzb93WwNYgjWDC6EEdkuC0cZEO7p3i/6RF1WutL8nxmnkxVx6UcUZJIy/LgP49622mO3/AA==&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;&quot;}'
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(className='mxgraph', style={"maxWidth": "100%"}, **{'data-mxgraph': unescape(mxgraph)}),
    DeferScript(src='https://viewer.diagrams.net/js/viewer-static.min.js')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: ok I will keep that solution in mind but I will keep my python solution as I understand it better. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pure JS solution you need to use MutationObserver. I've wrote a little helper function we are currently using that did the trick. Another suggestion would be to change the mutation to an element on screen then fire an event to handle the rest

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} id
 * @param {*} event
 * @param {(this: HTMLElement, ev: any) => any} callback
 * @param {boolean | AddEventListenerOptions} options
 */
function attachEventToDash(id, event, callback, options) {
    debugger;
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (_mutations, obs) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        if (ele) {
            debugger;
            ele.addEventListener(event, callback, options)
            obs.disconnect();
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        observer.observe(document, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    })
}
```